# Modelformset in django generic CreateView and UpdateView

Tags: python, django, modelform, formset

I have a model Organization with two fields 'id' and 'name'. I intend to populate it using dynamic model formsets.The code I have this far is as follows.

**forms**

```
class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('name',)

OrganizationFormset = modelformset_factory(Organization, form=OrganizationForm, fields=('name', ), extra=1)
```

**views**

```
class OrganizationCreate(CreateView):
    model = Organization
    form_class = OrganizationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrganizationCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = OrganizationFormset()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = OrganizationFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(formset=formset))


class OrganizationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Organization
    form_class = OrganizationForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrganizationUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = OrganizationFormset()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = OrganizationFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(formset=formset))
```

**template**
*create*

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %}
           {{ form }}
           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody>
                   {% for form in formset.forms %}
                   {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %}
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                         {% if form.instance.pk %}{{ form.DELETE }}{% endif %}

                         {{ form.field1 }}
                      </td>
                      <td>{{ form.name }}</td>
                   </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
           </table>
           {{ formset.management_form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Create Location">
       </form>
```

*update*

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}

           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody>
                   {% for form in formset.forms %}
                   {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %}
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                         {% if form.instance.pk %}{{ form.DELETE }}{% endif %}

                         {{ form.field1 }}
                      </td>
                      <td>{{ form.name }}</td>
                   </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
           </table>
           {{ formset.management_form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Update organizations">
       </form>
```

However, both the create template and the update template display pre-existing organizations while this should only be happening in the update template. Moreover, deleting pre-existing organizations in the update page  returns the following error:

```
The view aims.views.OrganizationUpdate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I am new to django generic views and working with formsets. What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `django model formsets` will show any items that it can find from database. So you have to override the `queryset` parameter, when creating one, to let it know which items to use and when. For example, you should provide -

```
Organization.objects.none()
```

for your create view like this -

```
class OrganizationCreate(CreateView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        context['formset'] = OrganizationFormset(queryset=Organization.objects.none()) # providing none

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        ...

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        ...
```

this will force the formset to render a blank form. Similarly change in update view to edit an specific item -

```
class OrganizationUpdate(UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrganizationUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = OrganizationFormset(queryset=Organization.objects.get(pk=< get the pk from url when editing>))
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        ...

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        ...
```

Hope this fixes your problem. If you still see the problem, then please update the question with details of urls and a possible screenshot. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Hi, how can I get the pk form the url?

Comment: That depends how you define your routes. If it is a route segment, then you can get it directly as a parameter to the respective class view method. for example - for a route like this for POST - `....user/edit/(?<pk>(\d+))/` I would use somthing like - `def post(self, request, *args, pk = none, **kwargs):` . Or, else you can always get it from `request` object.

Answer (score 3):

Your post method returns nothing when formset is invalid in both Class based views (create and update), you should return `form_invalid` in `else` branch:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    return self.form_valid(formset)
else:
    return self.form_invalid(formset)
```